# DataTable -> Python ->Django -> Expanded Row / Colspan problem / Searching, etc. does not work

Tags: python, django, datatable

I have a problem because I am trying to make a datatable with a drop down  when I click on a row and everything works. But then I lose the functionality of the datatable and can't search etc.

I have already searched half the internet and can't figure it out, maybe there is someone who could help?

Table.js

```
$('#clients_list').DataTable({
        buttons: ['copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pageLength'],
        responsive: true,
        "searching": true,
        retrieve: true,
        lengthChange: false,
        bDeferRender: true,
    })
        .buttons().container()
        .appendTo('#clients_list_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)');
```

Script:

```
`$(document).ready(function () {
            
            $(".expanded-row").hide();

            
            $(".expandable-row").click(function () {
                $(this).next(".expanded-row").toggle();
                $(".expanded-row").not($(this).next(".expanded-row")).hide();
            });
        });`
```

Table:

```
` <table style="width: 100%;"
                       class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered dataTable dtr-inline"
                id="clients_list">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Phone</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {% for c in clients_list %}
                        <tr class="expandable-row">
                            <td><a href="{% url 'client' c.id %}">{{ c }}</a></td>
                            <td>{{ c.email }}</td>
                            <td>{{ c.phone }}
                                <i class="fa fa-fw" aria-hidden="true" title="Copy to use phone"></i>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="expanded-row">
                            <td colspan="10">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="widget-chat-wrapper-outer">
                                                <b>
                                                    <div class="widget-title text-center opacity-10 text-uppercase">
                                                        Basic
                                                        information
                                                    </div>
                                                </b>
                                                <div tabindex="-1" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                                <div class="table-responsive-sm">
                                                    <table class="table table-nowrap mb-0 table-borderless"
                                                           style="table-layout: auto; width: 100%">
                                                        <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <th>Name & lastname:</th>
                                                            <td>{{ c }} ({{ c.name }})</td>
                                                            <th>Register date:</th>
                                                            <td>{{ c.reg_time }}</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="card-body"><h5 class="card-title">Comment history</h5>
                                            Chat widget
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                    </tfoot>
                </table> `
```

I'd be very grateful if someone could help make it so that everything works

I've tried so far to do it as row.child but that too doesn't work as I'd like because I can't do it there with "show already existing tr='expanded-row'", I've also tried to cheat datatable and as ajax make colspan on 'expanded-row' but then other tr don't want to hide with .hide or display:none function.

I have no idea anymore that's why I am writing to you guys